# Setting background color during mouse-over for PopupMenuBarItem

Tags: dojo

Looking for a little help figuring out how to change the background and
font color on a dijit.PopupMenuBarItem object during a mouse-over.  The
default color for a mouse-over is currently light blue when holding the pointer
over 'File' in the menu bar.  I've looked at cssStateNodes but I don't think this
is what I'm looking for. Currently using dojo 1.5.0 currently...

```
dojo.require("dijit.MenuBar");
dojo.require("dijit.MenuBarItem");
dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuBarItem");
dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
dojo.require("dijit.MenuItem");
dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuItem");

var pMenuBar;
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  pMenuBar = new dijit.MenuBar({
    style: "background-color: #495569"
    });

  var pSubMenu = new dijit.Menu({});
  pSubMenu.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
    label: "File item #1"
    }));

  pMenuBar.addChild(new dijit.PopupMenuBarItem({
    label: "File",
    style: "color: white",
    popup: pSubMenu
    }));

  pMenuBar.placeAt("dojoMenu");
  pMenuBar.startup();
});
```

Thanks for the help....

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to get this done:

```
var pSubMenu2 = new dijit.Menu({
  onFocus: function() {
    var obj = dijit.byId('editID');
    if (obj) {
      obj.attr('style','color: black');
    } 
  },
  onBlur: function() {
    var obj = dijit.byId('editID');
    if (obj) {
      obj.attr('style','color: white');
    } 
  },
  onMouseDown: function() {
    var obj = dijit.byId('editID');
    if (obj) {
      obj.attr('style','color: white');
    } 
  }
});

pSubMenu2.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
  onMouseOver: function() {
    var obj = dijit.byId('editID');
    if (obj) {
      obj.attr('style','color: black');
    }
  },
  label: "Edit item #1"
  }));

pSubMenu2.addChild(new dijit.MenuItem({
  onMouseOver: function() {
    var obj = dijit.byId('editID');
    if (obj) {
      obj.attr('style','color: black');
    }
  },
  label: "Edit item #2"
  }));

pMenuBar.addChild(new dijit.PopupMenuBarItem({
  id: "editID",
  label: "Edit",
  style: "color: white",
  onMouseOver: function() {
    this.attr('style','color: black');
  },
  onMouseLeave: function() {
    this.attr('style','color: white');
  },
  popup: pSubMenu2
  }));
```